# ¿Error al conectar hibernate y MyPHPadmin?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Verán me ocurre el siguiente error al ejecutar la conexión entre el local host y el proyecto maven con hibernate. Eh probado a crear usuarios de la base de datos nuevos con todos los privilegios a cambiar el driber por el que me dice en el error que se usa actualmente y nada tampoco me eh asegurado de que la salida del localhost es la 3306 y también de que la base de datos se llama contabilidad.

El error:

```
abr 16, 2019 2:36:48 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: contabilidad
    ...]
abr 16, 2019 2:36:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
abr 16, 2019 2:36:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
abr 16, 2019 2:36:48 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
abr 16, 2019 2:36:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
abr 16, 2019 2:36:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contabilidad]
abr 16, 2019 2:36:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}
abr 16, 2019 2:36:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
abr 16, 2019 2:36:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at modules.Login.probar(Login.java:110)
    at modules.Login.<init>(Login.java:104)
    at modules.Login$1.run(Login.java:38)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:55)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:65)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:853)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:360)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1434)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:986)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
    ... 49 more
```

El pom:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.izquierdo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Proyecto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

el documento persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="contabilidad">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contabilidad" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="contaJava" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

La clase producto:

```
  package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Producto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_Producto")
    private Integer idProducto;
    @Column(name = "Nombre", length = 100)
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "Precio")
    private double precio;
    @Column(name = "IVA")
    private int iva;
    @Column(name = "Impuesto_Equivalente")
    private int impuestoEquivalente;

    public Producto() {

    }

    public Producto(String nombre, double precio, int iva, int impuestoEquivalente) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.iva = iva;
        this.impuestoEquivalente = impuestoEquivalente;
    }

    public Integer getIdProducto() {
        return idProducto;
    }

    public void setIdProducto(Integer idProducto) {
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getIva() {
        return iva;
    }

    public void setIva(int iva) {
        this.iva = iva;
    }

    public int getImpuestoEquivalente() {
        return impuestoEquivalente;
    }

    public void setImpuestoEquivalente(int impuestoEquivalente) {
        this.impuestoEquivalente = impuestoEquivalente;
    }

}
```

La llamada a la conexion e insercion del objeto producto:

```
    package modules;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import entities.Producto;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Login extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtUsuario;
    private JTextField txtContrasea;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login frame = new Login();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Login() {
        setTitle("Registro de Contabilidad");
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("H:\\workSpaceEclipse\\Proyecto\\imagenes\\contaico.png"));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 336, 343);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblInicioDeSesion = new JLabel("Inicio de sesi\u00F3n");
        lblInicioDeSesion.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Condensed", Font.BOLD, 33));
        lblInicioDeSesion.setBounds(2, 11, 308, 42);
        lblInicioDeSesion.setHorizontalAlignment((int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.add(lblInicioDeSesion);

        JLabel lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario");
        lblUsuario.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Condensed", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblUsuario.setBounds(100, 64, 121, 36);
        lblUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment((int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.add(lblUsuario);

        JLabel lblContrasea = new JLabel("Contrase\u00F1a");
        lblContrasea.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblContrasea.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Condensed", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblContrasea.setBounds(100, 140, 121, 36);
        contentPane.add(lblContrasea);

        txtUsuario = new JTextField();
        txtUsuario.setBounds(57, 99, 206, 36);
        contentPane.add(txtUsuario);
        txtUsuario.setColumns(10);

        txtContrasea = new JTextField();
        txtContrasea.setColumns(10);
        txtContrasea.setBounds(51, 175, 212, 36);
        contentPane.add(txtContrasea);

        JButton btnRegistrarse = new JButton("Registrar");
        btnRegistrarse.setBounds(18, 258, 87, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnRegistrarse);

        JButton btnEntrar = new JButton("Entrar");
        btnEntrar.setBounds(115, 258, 87, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnEntrar);

        JButton btnSalir = new JButton("Salir");
        btnSalir.setBounds(212, 258, 87, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSalir);

        JLabel lblRecordarContrasea = new JLabel("Recordar contrase\u00F1a..");
        lblRecordarContrasea.setBounds(161, 222, 138, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblRecordarContrasea);
probar();

    }

    public void probar() {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("contabilidad");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Producto p = new Producto("asdsa",12.32,21,21);
        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

se me esta haciendo imposible arreglar esto y eh probado varias soluciones distintas nada a funcionado.

Este es el error que me aparece con el driver nuevo puesto podeis fijaros que es el mismo:

```
    abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: contabilidad
    ...]
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contabilidad]
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
abr 16, 2019 3:25:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at modules.Login.probar(Login.java:110)
    at modules.Login.<init>(Login.java:104)
    at modules.Login$1.run(Login.java:38)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:55)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:65)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:853)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.configureTimezone(MysqlaSession.java:360)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1434)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:986)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:843)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Bienvenido!, aumm yo intentaría primero cambiar el driver por el mensaje que está dándo acá: "`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'", coloca en el persistence: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" /> a ver

Comment: ... Porque te está dando error con la propiedad timezone: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support. Lo que quiere decir que revisamos el timezone o capaz el driver antiguo no es compatible con la misma.

Comment: @zerocool eso debería ser una respuesta.

Comment: al principio del post eh puesto ya que habia probado a poner el driver nuevo pero me seguia saliendo el mismo error no obstante gracias por responder, haber si consigo que funcione. Eh añadido el error que da con el driver puesto para mas informacion.

Comment: No lo coloco como respuesta porque era solo una idea :D, ya vi el comentario @genio125478, sorry. Intentaste ver lo de la zona horaria de la base de datos?

Comment: Fijate si este parámetro resuelve el problema: useLegacyDatetimeCode=false. (ejemplo: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contabilidad?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false). https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/

Comment: Lo eh puesto y sigue dando el mismo error incluido el de hora de verano. Lo gracioso es que en ecplipse oxigen no me da este error y funciona perfectamente pero en Eclipse Java 2019-03 si que me da error

Comment: Que te funciones en uno y en otro no entonces me da la impresión de que o es el driver o es la versión de java con respecto al driver. Revisa si el eclipse oxigen se ejecuta con una versión distinta de java, también habría que revisar la configuración de ejecución ya que uno puede estar pasando parámetros a la jvm que el otro no hace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de descubrir que ocurría ha sido el cambio horario de verano en otras palabras estamos en UTC +2 el *phpMyAdmin* eh probado con la siguiente sentencia `SET SESSION time_zone = '+2:00'` y después en el persistence.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contabilidad?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
```

Solucionado como Juan Palomo yo me lo guiso yo me lo como muchas gracias a todos por vuestras ayudas.